# T-SQL 2012 charindex comparing several strings does not match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In a SQL Server 2012 database, I want to find all the records where the `lastname` is not at least 'part' of the `teacherD` column.

The following SQL works about 90% of the time:

```
SELECT lastname, teacherD
FROM test.dbo.table145    
WHERE CHARINDEX(LOWER(lastName), LOWER([teacherD])) = 0
```

The problem is sometimes the `teacherD` column has special characters right next to the time. The above SQL thinks there is a difference.

Here are examples of where there are problems

```
lastname       teacherD  
--------------------------------
smith          smith, darell
smith          smith-bright joan
```

If possible the user would also like to check if part of lastname is contained within `teacherID`. Here are some examples of what I am referring to:

```
lastname       teacherD
------------------------------------
corbly-tip     corbly, annette b
baker-hage     cubs - bakerhage - 8c
king grie      king, bev
```

Please could you show me some SQL on how to solve part #1 and part #2?

Comment: Can you show a positive example, where it works as intended?

Comment: You can check if the last name is not present using `... where teacherD not like '%' + lastname + '%'`. It isn't clear if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the first part do this:

```
SELECT lastname, teacherD
FROM test.dbo.table145    
WHERE CHARINDEX(LOWER(lastName), LOWER('--'||[teacherD])) = 0
```

The problem you had what charindex was returning 0 because it was at location 0, so we add something to the start of the string that won't match so 0 returned will always be a fail.

I don't know what you want to do for the 2nd part.

Comment: I do not want a fail all the time. For example. 'smith'  from LastName and 'smith, darell' from teacherD should not be selected from the query above. 'Smith' is a subset of 
'Smith, Darell'. Basically if 'Smith' is part of 'Smith, Darell', then the record should not be selected. 
The Logic above needs to not include Smith, as part of the selection. The comma is making that record get selected.
Thus would you show me the sql to meet my requirements? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1816979 -- your comment makes no sense since the comma or dash after the string smith should have no effect on the return value.  Are you sure these strings are the same and one is not using an extended character set?